# how expand pivoted dataframe?

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse, expand

I want to get combination of all parameters after pivoting data frame. I have data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(parameter = c(rep("X",5), rep("Y",3)), value=c(letters[1:5],1:3))
```

I do the following transformation:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(parameter) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = parameter, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row)
```

my output is:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  X     Y    
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     1    
2 b     2    
3 c     3    
4 d     NA   
5 e     NA
```

my desired output:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 2
   X         Y
   <fct> <int>
 1 a         1
 2 b         1
 3 c         1
 4 d         1
 5 e         1
 6 a         2
 7 b         2
...
14 d         3
15 e         3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a solution based on the [expand.grid](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/expand.grid) function.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(parameter) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = parameter, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  expand.grid() %>%
  filter(!is.na(Y))
```

It's a rather dirty workaround, I'm sure there's another, more beautiful way.

Comment: after rubberducking question to SE. I arrived to exact solution. :D but instead of 
filter(!is.na(Y)) I've used distinct() as sometimes combinations with null is also valid.